# validation problem with jsf pages in eclipse helios

Tags: eclipse, jsf, eclipse-3.6, eclipse-wtp

Since I reinstalled Eclipse Helios I have a lot of these errors in my problems view:

```
Encountered "<EOF>" at line 0, column 0.
Was expecting one of:
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL> ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    "null" ...
    "(" ...
    "-" ...
    "not" ...
    "!" ...
    "empty" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    "not" ...
    "!" ...
    "-" ...
    "empty" ...
    "true" ...
    "false" ...
    <INTEGER_LITERAL> ...
    <FLOATING_POINT_LITERAL> ...
    <STRING_LITERAL> ...
    "null" ...
    "(" ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
```

I am sure I never had that before, the validation seems to fail on parts like that:

```
<f:facet name="header">                 
<ice:outputText value="ID"></ice:outputText>                                    
</f:facet>
#{bean.id}      <========= THIS LINE IS MARKED AS INVALID
</ice:column>
```

Why does this happen? What I can do against it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using EL in template text is only supported in Facelets 2.0 which is part of JSF 2.0. Apparently your dynamic web project is misconfigured as JSF 1.x and Eclipse will then jerk on that.

Change the JSF project facet version to 2.0 in your project's properties.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, this occurs in Helios when you are using #{} syntax outside a JSF component. Replace # with $, or use outputtext component with #{bean.id}